# Drag multiple vertices of different line features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, editing, vertices

Is it possible to drag multiple vertices of some parallel lines in QGIS at the same time?

I have a line-layer with parallel lines. In some regions I have to move the vertices of all parallel lines so that they still keep their distance to each other.

With the node tool I can only select the vertice of one of my lines I want to drag but not of multiple lines at the same time:
[image: only one vertex of different lines selectable]

In Multiline-Layers it is possible to drag all lines at the same time but that's not an option because I have to keep all attributes of my single lines.
[image]

Are there any other options to drag my lines all at the same time?

Edit1: Just found the **CadNodeTool** (https://github.com/wonder-sk/CadNodeTool ). With this plugin it is at least already possible to select vertices of multiple lines at the same time. Perhaps this plugin can be extended to move vertices of parallel lines.
[image]

Comment: I have been trying to crack this for a while! Hope a solution comes up soon!

Comment: Look at my edit comment

Comment: I suggest you to add the QAD-Plugin as an answer, otherwise people might think the best solution is the accepted answer, which doesn't seem to be the case for you.

Comment: good idea.Just added the answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible workaround, maybe good as just temporary solution for few data:

1. Enable **snapping** (Settings --> Snapping Options...). Set snap to vertex and set some tolerance.

[image]

2. Create a "dummy" line feature snapped on vertices you want move.

[image]

3. In snapping option check **Enable topological editing**
4. Activate node tool and select vertices of "dummy" line and move (hold Ctrl for selecting more vertices).

[image]

5. Done, you can delete the "dummy" feature or choose proper symbology if you give it special attribute or value.

Comment: Great idea for a workaround.I still hope there will be some other pythonic solution to build an own tool as we have several hundred kilometers to adjust.

Comment: pretty good idea for a plugin/core tool !

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved: Just found out, that the QAD-Plugin ( https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/ ) supports moving of vertices from different features:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

In QGIS 3.10 you can just activate the edit mode of the layer or the layers. In my case snapping is not activated. 
Use the vertex tool. Also here you can choose between "All Layers" or "Current Layer", depending if the lines you want to edit are in one layer or in different layers.

[image]

With this tool active you can select the vertices by rectangle. The vertices will be marked with a blue circle around them.

[image]

[image]

Next you click one of the vetices and then click on the spot where you want to move this vertex. And the other(s) will follow.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Try using affine transformation plugin. It allows move object with specific distance in X-axis and Y-axis

Edit: use Numerical Vertex Edit plugin, with that you can select single node and change its cordinates

Comment: I only want to move single vertices not the whole feature.

Comment: Oh my fault, let me think ;)

Comment: Look at my edit, it could be an answer for your problem. Slow one but it could works

Comment: I want to drag multiple vertices at the same time, so the numerical vertex edit plugin is not an option.